# What is the difference between "I used to" and "I had been" in this sentence?

Tags: past-perfect

> I used to live in the US for a year before I became a teacher.
>
> I had been living in the US for a year before I became a teacher.

Is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

**First sentence**

> I used to live in the US for a year before I became a teacher.

The expression [used to](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/used-to) describes a situation that no longer exists, or ceased to exist at some specified time. In this case, it means that the speaker
moved to the US, lived there for a year, moved away from the US and then (probably straight afterwards) became a teacher.

---

**Second sentence**

> I had been living in the US for a year before I became a teacher.

This sentence does not feel quite natural because both the [past perfect](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/past-tense/past-perfect) **had been** and the conjunction [before](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/before) indicate that something occurred before something else: in addition, **for a year** specifies a time interval. That sounds like it ought to define quite a complex sequence of events.

It could be made more natural by eliminating one of the before-indicators, like this:

> I **was** living in the US for a year before I became a teacher.

This sentence describes a situation where the speaker moved to the US, lived there for a year and (probably directly after that year) became a teacher.

> I had been living in the US for a year **when** I became a teacher.

This sentence describes a situation where the speaker moved to the US, lived there for a year and directly after that year became a teacher.

Alternatively, you could eliminate the time interval specifier, like this:

> I had been living in the US before I became a teacher.

This sentence describes a situation where the speaker moved to the US and stayed there for a while, but left some time before becoming a teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the two sentences mean different things. The first is hard to parse.

> I used to live in the US for a year before I became a teacher.

Saying "used to [do something]" means that whatever you used to do, you don't do anymore.

- I used to hate black-eyed peas.

Unstated, but part of the meaning, is that you like them now. So saying "I used to live in the US for a year" means that you don't live there any more, but you were there for a year.  Ending the sentence with "before I became a teacher" does not fit with the rest of the flow of the sentence.  My guess at the meaning would be that you are a teacher now, somewhere other than the US, but you did happen to live in the US for a year prior to being a teacher.

> I had been living in the US for a year before I became a teacher.

This second sentence sounds normal to this native speaker. It means that you are a teacher now, most likely in the US, and you were in the US a year before becoming a teacher.  I should rephrase that.  Technically, it is not necessarily saying you are a teacher now. At a minimum you had been a teacher, and before that you had been in the US for a year.